# Polyline is not pointing to correct langitude.latitude data in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am trying to add polyline in my existing leaflet map. But unfortunately its not overlapping the correct coordinates.

[image]

```
this.testd = [
            [26.946345158021394, 45.30658810117468], [31.74737690870502, 58.27657611253403], [3.572373155835759, 50.87794848675696]
        ]

        this.pathLine = L.polyline(this.testd);
        this.allLayers.addLayer(this.pathLine);
        this.allLayers.addTo(this.map);
```

Please let me know how to make it work.

Comment: A classic case of latitude-longitude versus longitude-latitude. Read https://macwright.org/lonlat/ .

Comment: OMG such a relief. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct order of coordinates when specifying geographical points in Leaflet is `[latitude, longitude]`, so you have to reverse your coordinates in `this.testd` array.

Comment: Yeah i got that. Such a silly mistake. Now i am using : L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(filteredFeatureDataCoordinates); to swap and solve.